# Can maven tell eclipse to ignore warnings in generated code?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, code-generation

I have a collection of Java projects.  It is a series of APIs.  I am generating much of the server code from the swagger definition using swagger codegen. I'm using spring-boot with the delegate pattern, so my generated code all goes to `src/gen/java/main` and I can write my implementation code in `src/main/java`.  The generated code is not version controlled, but re-generated as needed by the maven swagger codegen plugin.  All this works nicely :)

However, when I first import the projects into Eclipse (using "import existing maven project" on the parent project to import them all) I get a bunch of "unused function" type warnings from the generated code. (I add the `src/gen/java/main` folder as a source folder using the *build-helper-maven-plugin*.)  If I select the `src/gen/java/main` folder in each project, right-click, choose properties and say *Ignore optional compile problems* then this goes away (I also mark it as a derived resource)

***Question: is there some way to mark this folder in the pom so that when I (or a colleague) imports the project into Eclipse, these settings are already set on that folder?  Alternatively, some way to tell eclipse to always treat folders with the name (relative to project route) in that fashion?***

**Additional Info**

I was asked for the pom file in a comment.  I have done a fairly minimal example:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.example.api</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Example</name>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <springfox-version>2.7.0</springfox-version>
        <swagger.codegen.version>2.4.0-SNAPSHOT</swagger.codegen.version> 
        <jetty-version>9.2.15.v20160210</jetty-version>
        <slf4j-version>1.7.21</slf4j-version>
        <junit-version>4.12</junit-version>
        <servlet-api-version>2.5</servlet-api-version>
        <springfox-version>2.7.0</springfox-version>
        <jackson-version>2.8.9</jackson-version>
        <jackson-threetenbp-version>2.6.4</jackson-threetenbp-version>
        <spring-version>4.3.9.RELEASE</spring-version>
    </properties>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>                   
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>${swagger.codegen.version}</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>generate</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>              
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>com.example.api.Swagger2SpringBoot</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>assemble-all</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Needed to create swagger bits in asynch manner -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${swagger.codegen.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>foo</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/spec/foo.yaml</inputSpec>                     
                            <modelPackage>com.example.api.models</modelPackage>
                            <apiPackage>com.example.api</apiPackage>
                            <language>spring</language>
                            <invokerPackage>com.example.api</invokerPackage>
                            <basePackage>com.example.api</basePackage>
                            <withXml>true</withXml>
                            <configOptions>
                                <artifactId>bookings</artifactId>
                                <artifactDescription>Bookings API</artifactDescription>
                                <title>Bookings API</title>
                                <artifactUrl>https://api.example.com/foo</artifactUrl>
                                <groupId>com.example.api</groupId>
                                <artifactVersion>1.0</artifactVersion>
                                <configPackage>com.example.api.config</configPackage>
                                <serializableModel>true</serializableModel>
                                <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                                <java8>true</java8>
                                <async>true</async>
                                <library>spring-boot</library>      
                                <delegatePattern>true</delegatePattern>
                                <useBeanValidation>true</useBeanValidation>
                                <useOptional>true</useOptional> 
                                <hideGenerationTimestamp>true</hideGenerationTimestamp>                                                             
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jetty-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webAppConfig>
                        <contextPath>/v2</contextPath>
                    </webAppConfig>
                    <webAppSourceDirectory>target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</webAppSourceDirectory>
                <stopPort>8079</stopPort>
                <stopKey>stopit</stopKey>
                <httpConnector>
                    <port>8002</port>
                    <idleTimeout>60000</idleTimeout>
                </httpConnector>
            </configuration>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-jetty</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                        <daemon>true</daemon>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop-jetty</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--SpringFox dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>${springfox-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>${springfox-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Bean Validation API support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

This uses a minimal foo.yaml:

```
swagger: '2.0'
info: 
  title: Foo API
  description: Test case
  version: 1.0
  host: api.example.com
basePath: /
schemes:
  - https
consumes:
  - application/json
produces:
  - application/json

tags:
  - name: foo
parameters:
  message:
    name: message
    in: body
    description: Foo
    schema:
      $ref: '#/definitions/Message'
    required: true
definitions:
  Message:
    type: object
    description: Foo
    properties:
      heading:
        type: string
        description: heading
      body:
        type: string
        description: body
paths:
  /foo:
    post:
      summary: foo
      operationId: postFoo
      tags:
        - foo
      parameters:
        - $ref: '#/parameters/message'
      responses:
         '202':
            description: Messages will be sent
         default:
          description: An unexpected error occurred
```

If I just `mvn clean compile` then import this the it's fine.  However, if I add any implementation code that uses the generated code then it isn't.

For example, I added a package `com.example.api.implementation` to `src/main/java` containing a file *FooApi.java* which was:

```
package com.example.api.implementation;

import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.example.api.FooApiDelegate;
import com.example.api.models.Message;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

@Component
public class FooApi implements FooApiDelegate {
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    private final HttpServletRequest request;

    public Optional<ObjectMapper> getObjectMapper() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(objectMapper);
    }

    public Optional<HttpServletRequest> getRequest() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(request);
    }

    @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
    public FooApi(ObjectMapper objectMapper, HttpServletRequest request) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
        this.request = request;
    }

    @Override
    public CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<Void>> postFoo( Message  message) {
        return new CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<Void>>();
    }
}
```

If I now import, I get errors *FooApiDelegate cannot be resolved to a type* and *Message cannot be resolved to a type* (and for the corresponding imports) from my non.generated file.

Comment: If the plugin it doing it's work correctly it should generate into `          <output>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</output>` by default which is not under version control it is in `target` directory and should be correctly picked up by Eclipse etc. But you have written to changed the location to `src/gen/java/main`? ...After taking a short look into the source of the plugin you should remove your configuration for the `output` and just keep the defaults...that should do the trick...otherwise please add your full pom here...

Comment: @khmarbaise: I did indeed have `<output>${project.basedir}</output>` (and a `sourceFolder`) in my pom.  Removing them means the generated code ends in in `target/generated-srouces/swagger/src/main/java` instead of just `src/gen/java/main`  But unless I make that a source folder I now get errors in Eclipse that it can't find those classes.  If I make it a source folder, I get the same warnings

Comment: @khmarbaise: Added example pom (and yaml and implementation code needed to repeat the problem)

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two issues. The first thing is that you explicitly suppressed the execution of the code generation by using `org.eclipse.m2e`.. this will suppress any kind of generation you might have. Furthermore you are using a `2.4.0-SNAPSHOT` where you should use [`3.0.0-rc0` instead](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22io.swagger%22%20AND%20a%3A%22swagger-codegen-maven-plugin%22). Unfortunately the 3.0.0-rc0 has failured so you should stick with 2.3.1 which is a release instead of SNAPSHOT's.

Apart from that the plugin is missing also things are not correctly handled...If you cleanly import the project in Eclipse you will get a dialog about `Setup Maven Plugin Connectors`. Furthermore the plugin does not correctly handle the update in Eclipse context which can be done...

If you import the project and manually add the source folders from `target/generated-sources` this will work but unfortunately not allways...

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean about the m2e plugin.  Should I just remove that entirely?  I tried changing to swagger codegen version 2.3.1 and removing the `pluginManagement` section in the pom.  Then importing (without generating first?).  I get an error in Eclipse: _No marketplace entries found to handle swagger-codegen-maven-plugin:2.3.1:generate in Eclipse._ I'm pretty sure it was googling this and how to get around it that lead me to add the lifecycle management plugin in the first place.  Can you post an example of how the pom should look?

Comment: In terms of the swagger codegen version, the 3.0 RC-0 doesn't support many languages/libraries yet.  The [release note](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/releases/tag/v3.0.0-rc0) says _java and inflector are the only supported languages_ which appears to mean a Java client and inflector server stub.  I'm using spring-boot server so it's not yet possible for me.  And it's only an RC.  I'm actually building with my own patch of 2.4.0 until my PR that fixes a bug in the spring boot templates is merged... But that won't affect this problem.